# Gradient fill conditional upon number of instances of specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, countif

I'm trying to use a header row for conditional formatting that shows a gradient (stronger colour of red) depending on how many occurrences of text are in the cells in each column. For example, if there are two instances of text in the column below, the top header row cell will be a lighter shade of red. If there were 20 instances of text in the column below, the top header row cell would be a darker shade of red.

Does someone have a straight forward way of making this work? I suspect it will be based on a 'count if' formula but unclear on how best to go about what I suspect will be a very straightforward operation.

Answer (score 0):

If prepared to add a formula in Row1 such as:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A12,"a")
```

copied across to suit, then a Graded Color Scale should suit:

[image: SO25607497 example]

Here the relevant text has been chosen to be `a`.

Comment: That looks pretty straight forward except that the text is random and has no consistent word or letter. I'm trying with count blank instead. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: only need to count if there's text, no numbers involved. I what does the =11 bit do?